# How change the material of gltf object in three.js

Tags: three.js, gltf

I imported a gltf file to three.js by GLTFLoader.

But I dont know why, when I apply material. It just change to single color, not like I apply material for a box which was created by three.js. [Image about Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPyjV.png)

Can you give me some advice ?

Thank you.

```
function loadMaterials() {
    const materialsPath = './mat/';
    const select = document.getElementById('materialList');

    const materialFiles = ['wood1.jpg', 'wood2.jpg', 'wood3.jpg'];

    materialFiles.forEach(file => {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = materialsPath + file;
        option.text = file.split('.')[0];
        select.appendChild(option);
    });
}


window.onload = loadMaterials;
function applyMaterial() {
    if (!selectedObject) return;

    const materialName = document.getElementById('materialList').value;
    const materialTexture = textureLoader.load(materialName);
    const newMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ map: materialTexture });

    selectedObject.traverse((child) => {
        if (child.isMesh) {
            child.material = newMaterial;
            child.material.needsUpdate = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Three.js, GLTF edit material

Comment: I think we need more info here, your screenshot clearly shown textures so they look fine. We have no idea what could be happening here, how your files work, etc... You are technically updating materials in the right way as far as I can see, so... What is `textureLoader` and how it defined?

Comment: Also see the "Textures" section of THREE.GLTFLoader docs, you may need to configure the texture's flipY and colorSpace properties:
https://threejs.org/docs/?q=gltf#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader

Comment: @somethinghere I created it outside before: const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
I mean, I added material to gltf object, but It's not show the wood material like box beside. It's just a single color.